# Remove duplicates of a List, selecting by a property value in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, list, duplicates

I have a list of objects that I need some duplicates removed from. We consider them duplicates if they have the same Id and prefer the one whose booleanValue is false. Here's what I have so far:

```
objects.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.Where(y => !y.booleanValue));
```

I've determined that GroupBy is doing no such grouping, so I don't see if any of the other functions are working. Any ideas on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of x.ID?

Comment: @allonhadaya it's an int.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var results = 
    from x in objects
    group x by x.Id into g
    select g.OrderBy(y => y.booleanValue).First();
```

For every `Id` it finds in `objects`, it will select the first element where `booleanValue == false`, or the the first one (if none of them have `booleanValue == false`).

If you prefer fluent syntax:

```
var results = objects.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                     .Select(g => g.OrderBy(y => y.booleanValue).First());
```

Comment: I do prefer fluent syntax. :)
Thank you. As a side note for someone else who finds this, I added ".ToList()" after the last parenthesis and set "objects =" instead of "var results =". This way I could make permanent changes to the list, as it were.

Comment: @p.s.w.g What if I dont want to remove all duplicates but always leave one left in the list?

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working for my list of objects. I still get duplicates returned. Please see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316343/groupby-to-remove-duplicates-from-ienumerable-list-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var result =
    objects.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(g =>
        g.FirstOrDefault(y => !y.booleanValue) ?? g.First())
```

This assumes that your objects are of a reference type.

Another possibility might be to use `Distinct()` with a custom `IEqualityComparer<>`.

Answer (score 0):

This partially answers the question above, but I justed need a really basic solution:

```
objects.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
       .Select(x => x.First())
       .ToArray();
```

The key to getting the original object from the `GroupBy()` is the `Select()` getting the `First()` and the `ToArray()` gets you an array of your objects, not a Linq object.